# Why does a trailing newline (\\) change alignment of my equation?

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I have 2 equations with two equality signs each. The equality signs should be vertically aligned. I can produce the expected output like this:<sup>1</sup>
<sub>Please read the footnote if you think this is just the wrong approach. You're right.</sub>

```
% Full MWE at the bottom of the question
\begin{align*}
foooo &= bar &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= baz \\
abc &= defgh  &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= xyz
\end{align*}
```

[image: Output 1]

But if I just at a (seemingly) innocent `\\` to the end of the second equation, the `\hspace` apparently has no effect anymore:

```
\begin{align*}
foooo &= bar &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= baz \\
abc &= defgh  &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= xyz \\
\end{align*}
%
\begin{align*}
foooo &= bar &&= baz \\
abc &= defgh  &&= xyz \\
\end{align*}
```

[image: Output 2]

I used to think that `\\` has no effect in the last line of an equation. Now, this example proves me wrong.

> **Question**: I would like to understand why the trailing `\\` changes the alignment in my equation / why it defeats the effect of `\hspace{-3.6cm}`.

I added an `scrartcl` tag because I realized that the behavior is different in `article`. My question is based on `scrartcl`.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
foooo &= bar &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= baz \\
abc &= defgh  &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= xyz 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
foooo &= bar &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= baz \\
abc &= defgh  &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= xyz \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I *know* that I shouldn't be using negative whitespace as shown in my example but rather `alignat`:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
foooo &= bar &&= baz \\
abc &= defgh  &&= xyz
\end{alignat*}
```

However, the point of this question is *not* how to produce a certain alignment but to *understand* why the trailing `\\` matters.

Comment: The `\\\` adds another empty equation, and in this equation the second alignment is wider than in the first two lines: indeed, in these the width of the left hand side of the equation is negative, while in the last line it is zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the observed behaviour is not really the trailing `\\`, but rather the fact that there is a third line without `\hspace{-3.6cm}`. In the code below I have added such a line inbetween, so there is no trailing `\\`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
foooo &= bar &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= baz \\
abc &= defgh  &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= xyz 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
foooo &= bar &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= baz \\
abc &= defgh  &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= xyz\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
foooo &= bar &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= baz \\
      &      &               &      \\
abc &= defgh  &\hspace{-3.6cm}&= xyz 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]